# How to read the HTML DOM in protractor

Tags: javascript, dom, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I want to retrieve the value for our version which is stored in HTML DOM.

[image]

Using node.js and protractor. I don't know how to go about it.

Please provide your valuable knowledge for the same :)

I want the value 2016.R08.1.RC1

Comment: Please provide some code, what did you try :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to select `html` by selector and get `manifest` property:

```
element(by.css('html')).getAttribute('manifest');
```

Then you should receive the full value of `manifest` property.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, I use your advice and get following error :                                      Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'stack' of Error while waitin
g for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This coul
d be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves cli
ent-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See h
ttp://git.io/v4gXM for details"

Comment: Can you know why is this happening?

Comment: As error message clearly says, you're probably running Protractor on non-angular page. If so, use [Webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've just come through this question and it's answer while doing protractor e2e angular 5/6 tests.

The answer from @Konstantin Azizov is good but `element(by.css('html')).getAttribute('manifest')` **will return a promise not the value itself** indicated by it's API:

So you can do something like:

```
element(by.css('html')).getAttribute('manifest').then((data) => {
  elementHtmlValue = data;
});
```

The content then of `elementHtmlValue` is what you are looking for :)